# Upload max file size for BotFramework DirectLine

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm developing a native iOS app which is using Microsoft's BotFramework DirectLine API. I'm having problems when trying to use the upload endpoint when the user uses the iPhone camera to take a picture.

The response I get back from the API is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError"
  }
}
```

First I thought it was by code... Then, after testing with other images, I come to the conclusion that there must be a max file size limit when using the upload endpoint.

So my question is, is there a max upload file size limit for the upload endpoint, and if so, what is it?

If there is, does that mean I have to implement my own file upload API and then pass the URL to this uploaded file in a message which I post to the DirectLine activities endpoint?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you're hitting a size limit. Can you send a conversation ID of a case where you hit this error and I can see what the internal error is?

Comment: Did you try to set max upload size in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Per Stack Overflow user [@nilsw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5199616/nilsw) email:

> The Direct Line API has a 4mb limit as of 2017-12-27 - You can read more in the discussion here:
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/789